# Chrome permissions - user message for system.display

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have added a new permission `system.display` added to my extension in the `manifest.json` file.
I expected that there would be a new permission listed for the extension but it is not. Checked listed permissions by navigating to `chrome://extensions` and then click on `details` link under the installed extension.
Also I did not find associated message with this permission in [Chromium](https://github.com/chromium/chromium).

Could it be that this permission is granted silently?

Comment: Yup.  Many permissions like the unlimitedStorage, webRequest, and webRequestBlocking are granted silently.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc correctly pointed out - many permissions are granted silently and are not listed.

You can read about these permissions here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings#nowarning

**General rule regarding permissions:**

If they access user data (bookmarks, pages through contentscript, management, location, history, etc) they are listed and warnings are generated.
Permission for such items need to be asked explicitly and these are listed in details for the extension.

**For system info api like system.memory, system.cpu, etc are not accessing any user info. So these permissions are granted implicitly.**